# ¿ la funcion funcion move_uploaded_file, no funciona?

Tags: php

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]uso la funcion move_uploaded_file, y no funiona, no arroja errores, intento subir una imagen, esta se sube correctamente a el archivo temporal tmp, pero no la puedo mover con la [image: funcion move_uploaded_file], no  da ningun error de permisos, y las rutas estan como se muestran en las imagenes,

alguna sugerencia ?

cuando cambio la ruta $nombre_archivo = "$carpeta/nick.png"; a $nombre_archivo = "nick.png"; si funciona y me guarda la imagen pero cuando intento moverla a una carpeta no funciona.

acabe de hacer la correciones y  tampoco se soluciona:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name-game'];
$archivo = $_FILES['picture'];

echo"el  archivo subido es: ";
var_dump($archivo);
echo "<br>";
echo"el nombre es: ";
var_dump($archivo['tmp_name']);
echo "<br>";
echo '<img src="dir/img/foto3.png" alt="imagen de prueba">';
$carpeta = "dir/img";
// $nombre_archivo = "$carpeta/nick.png";
$nombre_archivo = $carpeta."/nick.png";
echo "la ruta y nombre de archivo a mover sera en : ";
echo $nombre_archivo;
move_uploaded_file ($archivo['tmp_name'], "$nombre_archivo");
if (move_uploaded_file ($archivo['tmp_name'] ,                          
"$nombre_archivo"))
{
echo "<br>";
echo "se copio el archivo";
}
else
{
echo "<br>";
echo "NO se copio el archivo";
}
//header("Location: index.php");
?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, considera poner el código como texto y no como imagen. ¿El problema dices es cuando usas el valor de `$carpeta`? ¿Qué hay en ese valor? ¿Es una ruta correcta, qué permisos tienes en esa ruta?

Comment: En la imagen se observa que estarías duplicando el carácter `/`, pues lo tienes al final de `$carpeta` y al inicio del eventual nombre del archivo, resultando en una ruta errónea, inexistente. Revisa el mensaje, al final, te está diciendo que la ruta será: `dir/img//nick.png`, observa bien, hay dos `//` antes de `nick.png`

Comment: Donde pones: `$nombre_archivo = "$carpeta/nick.png"`, debes concatenar la variable con la cadena así: `$nombre_archivo = $carpeta."/nick.png"`. Amén de lo mencionado en los otros comentarios sobre: `//`

Comment: hice las correcciones y tampoco se soluciona :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En tu código actual estás llamando dos veces a `move_uploaded_file()`.

Por otra parte, conviene verificar siempre si el directorio existe y si el usuario actual tiene permisos de escritura para este tipo de casos.

Intenta lo siguiente, así, si no funciona, sabrás cuál es el motivo del error:

```
$name = $_POST['name-game'];
$archivo = $_FILES['picture'];
$carpeta = "dir/img";
$nombre_archivo = "$carpeta/nick.png";
echo "la ruta y nombre de archivo a mover sera en : $nombre_archivo";

if (is_dir($carpeta) && is_writable($carpeta)) {
    if( move_uploaded_file($archivo['tmp_name'], $nombre_archivo) ) {
      echo "<br />se copio el archivo";         
    } else {
      echo "Error: ".$archivo["error"];
    }
} else {
    echo "No tienes permiso para escribir en $carpeta o bien $carpeta no existe";
}
```

[Aquí tienes los códigos de error posibles](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php), para que sepas, en caso de que entre en el `else`, por qué está fallando.

Comment: gracias soluciono mi problema, di permisos de escritura al directorio dir/img